# Alert when the billing info address and the shipping info address are the same

Tags: php, jquery

I've built and order object which outputs the current variables as shown below.

I would like the alert to be...the two divs highlighted green. I'm assuming i'll need to incorporate some jquery.. here's what i have:

```
<div class='address_info left'>
            <h3>Billing Info</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><label>Account No: </label><?php echo $order->patient_id;?></li>
                <li><label>Name: </label><?php echo trim($order->billing_address['name']); ?></li>
                <li><label>Address 1: </label><?php echo trim($order->billing_address['addr1']);?></li>
                <li><label>Address 2: </label><?php echo trim($order->billing_address['addr2']);?></li>
                <li><label>City, State, Zip:</label><?php echo trim($order->billing_address['city'] . ' ' . $order->billing_address['state'] . ' ' . $order->billing_address['zip']);?></li>
                <li><label>Email: </label><a href='mailto:<?php echo $order->customer_email;?>'>Send Customer Email</a></li>
                <li><label>Phone: </label><?php echo $order->customer_phone;?></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
        <div class='address_info right'>
            <h3>Shipping Info</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><label>Name: </label><?php echo $order->shipping_address['name']; ?></li>
                <li><label>Address 1: </label><?php echo $order->shipping_address['addr1'];?></li>
                <li><label>Address 2: </label><?php echo $order->shipping_address['addr2'];?></li>
                <li><label>City, State, Zip:</label><?php echo $order->shipping_address['city'] . ' ' . $order->shipping_address['state'] . ' ' . $order->shipping_address['zip']?></li>
                <li><label></label></li>
                <li><label></label></li>
                <li><label></label></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I'm currently using some css on hover for colors.

```
div.address_info.left:hover {
    background: red;
    color: #fff; }

div.address_info.right:hover {
    background: #5C991F;
    color: #fff; }

div.order_info:hover {
    background: #3366FF;
    color: #fff; }
```

So here's my update:

```
if (count(array_diff($this->billing_address, $this->shipping_address)) > 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
```

I guess my real question is how to run a jquery event on my data. Sorry for  being so vague again at the start.. i guess we didn't get off on the right foot. Would love some help with the jQuery though. Thanks in advance.

Thanks for all the help.. i figured it out!

```
if($order->check_addresses())
    $class='same';
else
    $class='different';

    <div class='address_info left <?php echo $class; ?>'>
         <div class='address_info right <?php echo $class; ?>'>
```

and than the css

```
div.same {background-color: green;}
div.different {background-color: red;}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ], please.

Comment: I suggest: Use PHP to determine whether the content is the same. If it is, apply a CSS class to the DIVS to indicate identical content.

Comment: elaborate on that showdev please

Comment: @timothyradzikowski I've answered that, and am being downvoted for being courteous to you.

Comment: @TimothyRadzikowski Stack Overflow is not a code sourcing site, as it stands your question does not show any attempt to answer the question itself, you simply explain what you are attempting to do. The downvotes are due to this fact. They are a suggestion that you should attempt to solve the problem, possibly with a bit of help from google as well. and then post a question (or edit this one) when you get stuck at a describable point.

Comment: Thanks again guys for pointing this out.. i've added some additons using array diff to ensure my values are the same ... now i need help with the jquery.

Comment: If you are doing the comparison on the server there is no need for jQuery, just use CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a hidden input you could do this very easily. Here is an example using your code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
    { 
    var BillAddy = $("#billing").val();
    var ShipAddy = $("#shipping").val();

    if(BillAddy == ShipAddy)
        {
            $(".address_info ").css("backgroundColor","#00FF00");
            return true;
        }
    return false;
    });
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class='address_info left'>
            <h3>Billing Info</h3>
            <ul>
            <input type="hidden" id="billing" value="<?php echo $order->billing_address; ?>" />
                <li><label>Account No: </label><?php echo $order->patient_id;?></li>
                <li><label>Name: </label><?php echo trim($order->billing_address['name']); ?></li>
                <li><label>Address 1: </label><?php echo trim($order->billing_address['addr1']);?></li>
                <li><label>Address 2: </label><?php echo trim($order->billing_address['addr2']);?></li>
                <li><label>City, State, Zip:</label><?php echo trim($order->billing_address['city'] . ' ' . $order->billing_address['state'] . ' ' . $order->billing_address['zip']);?></li>
                <li><label>Email: </label><a href='mailto:<?php echo $order->customer_email;?>'>Send Customer Email</a></li>
                <li><label>Phone: </label><?php echo $order->customer_phone;?></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
        <div class='address_info right'>
            <h3>Shipping Info</h3>
            <ul>
                <input type="hidden" id="shipping" value="<?php echo $order->shipping_address; ?>" />
                <li><label>Name: </label><?php echo $order->shipping_address['name']; ?></li>
                <li><label>Address 1: </label><?php echo $order->shipping_address['addr1'];?></li>
                <li><label>Address 2: </label><?php echo $order->shipping_address['addr2'];?></li>
                <li><label>City, State, Zip:</label><?php echo $order->shipping_address['city'] . ' ' . $order->shipping_address['state'] . ' ' . $order->shipping_address['zip']?></li>
                <li><label></label></li>
                <li><label></label></li>
                <li><label></label></li>
            </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help, i got it done and you can see my edits above. Although i didn't use your code I'll have it noted for future reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You were correct to include PHP and jquery.  You can do that either on the client in JavaScript or on the server in PHP. Give it a try and come back when you have problems.

In the PHP you can use the result of the comparison to set a CSS class on the divs.  then in the style sheet set the background-color based on that class.

In JavaScript it would be more complicated, but would not require a trip to the server.

Comment: Wasn't me that downvoted, but I would suggest this should be a comment.

Comment: everybodys downvoting everything.. what gives...  ehhh

Comment: It answers the OPs question without spoon feeding.  Some people are just too quick to downvote.  I would have left the what have you tried comment, but it was already there, o I just up voted it and the "you beat me to it".

Comment: Well, i've updated a bit using array diff to find my values.. need help with jQuery.. Sorry for any confusion Mr. Wooster. =]

Comment: +1 for providing an answer without eliminating the need for the poster to make an effort.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite, I really try not to spoon feed.

Comment: I finally got it and thanks for all the help. You can see my new edits above.